# Sorting list of pairs by the second element of the pairs in scheme

Tags: sorting, scheme

I have procedure in scheme which give me a list of pairs and I need to sort descending this list by the second element of the pairs. Like this:

```
((1 . 1) (2 . 3) (3 . 2)) --> ((2 . 3) (3 . 2) (1 . 1))
((1 . 1) (x . 3) (2 . 1) (3 . 1)) --> ((x . 3) (1 . 1) (2 . 1) (3 . 1))
((1 . 3) (3 . 4) (2 . 2)) --> ((3 . 4) (1 . 3) (2 . 2))
```

I have no idea how I should use sorting for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the built-in [`sort`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/list..rkt%29._sort%29%29) procedure:

```
(define (sort-desc-by-second lst)
  (sort lst
        (lambda (x y) (> (cdr x) (cdr y)))))

(sort-desc-by-second '((1 . 1) (2 . 3) (3 . 2)))
=> '((2 . 3) (3 . 2) (1 . 1))
```

The trick here is passing to `sort` an appropriate comparison procedure as the second parameter.

Comment: I thought it will be more difficult and it is so easy, thanks.

Comment: What is the complexity of this inbuilt procedure? I ask because I used this on 500,000 elements and this is taking time.

Comment: @RohitShinde `O(n log n)` as usual, bear in mind that it's for immutable lists.

Comment: Are lists immutable by default? I created a pair of lists using the map function like this `(map list list1 list2)` where list1 and list2 are 500,000 elements each. I applied the above procedure on the list created using that function. So would this work?

Comment: @RohitShinde whether the lists are immutable or not depends on what interpreter you're using. But chances are that the sorting algorithm is implemented in an immutable fashion (check the documentation).

Comment: I am using guile scheme. I think it is immutable. I'll check the documentation though.