# Sort with R5RS scheme in DrRacket

Tags: sorting, scheme, racket

I'm learning scheme using DrRacket version 7.0.

I have copied, and modified, the following procedure from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13590831/68571).

```
#lang racket

(define sort-asc-by-second
  (lambda (lst)
    (sort lst
          (lambda (x y) (< (cdr x) (cdr y))))))
```

And it works perfectly.

Now I have change the `#lang racket` instruction with this one `#lang r5rs`.

And DrRacket complains with the following error:

> sort: unbound identifier in: sort

Do I forget to add something to DrRacket (libraries, modules, etc.)? Or maybe `sort` is not available in R5RS.

Comment: Indeed, R5RS does not include sorting. (It's a pretty small language standard.) There are a couple of sorting SRFIs (95, 132) that you could probably use if you're determined to use R5RS.

Comment: I had the same problem once. I took C++ code and just added into my Java project. I have no idea why the two languages code were not interchangeable. They are both C dialects just like `#lang racket` and `#!r5rs` are Scheme dialects. GCC compiles both so why not?

Comment: It seems that people are stupid. I'm asking: **Do I forget to add something to DrRacket (libraries, modules, etc.)?**, and they answer me that racket and r5rs are Scheme dialects. It seems hat they like to have their minute of glory making fun.

Comment: They are different languages with different libraries and primitives. Just like GCC supports many languages, including it's own version of C which is not standard, the racket suit supports many languages. Thus changing the first line from `#lang racket` to `#!r5rs` is much like trying to switch from `gcc` to `g++` and hope it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [R5RS report](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/index.html) there is no such thing as `sort`. You may fetch the reference implementation for `sort` from [SRFI-95 Sorting and merging](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-95/srfi-95.html). It's not 100% compatible with the `#lang racket` one. R5RS doesn't have libraries so the portable way would be to `load` it or inline it.

[R6RS](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r6rs/r6rs-std/index.html) has superseded R5RS and it has [`list-sort`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-5.html) in its standard library.

R7RS-Large, which is not yet fully ratified, uses [SRFI-132](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-132/srfi-132.html) as it sorting library `(scheme sort)` which also has `list-stable-sort` which is the same as the R6RS `list-sort`.

In Racket you can mix and match libraries from all the languages it supports, but it does not work for lists that are implemented differently and it is a lock in. Being dependent on a different languages library means you cannot run the code with other implementations, like Ikarus and Chez.